# Counting number of digits in an integer through recursion

Tags: c++

My code is following:

/counting number of digits in an integer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int countNum(int n,int d){
    if(n==0)
    return d;
    else
    return (n/10,d++);
}
int main(){
    int n;
    int d;
    cout<<"Enter number"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
   int x=countNum();
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

i cannot figure out the error,it says that 
: too few arguments to function `int countNum(int, int)' 
what is issue?

Comment: Look at `countNum(int n,int d)`.  Then look at `countNum();`.  Now look back at `countNum(int n,int d)`.  See the problem?

Comment: Is this for an assignment?  Using recursion for this (and not taking advantage of tail-end-recursion), would flood the call stack for no good reason ...

Answer (score 6):

Because you declared the function to take two arguments:

```
int countNum(int n,int d){
```

and you are passing none in:

```
int x = countNum();
```

You probably meant to call it like this, instead:

```
int x = countNum(n, d);
```

---

Also this:

```
return (n/10,d++);
```

should probably be this:

```
return countNum(n/10,d++);
```

---

Also you are not initializing your `n` and `d` variables:

```
int n;
int d;
```

---

Finally you don't need the `d` argument at all. Here's a better version:

```
int countNum(int n){
    return (n >= 10)
        ? 1 + countNum(n/10)
        : 1;
}
```

and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1aaa3ae20ebf0331)'s the working example.

Answer (score 2):

`int x=countNum();` the caller function should pass actual arguments to calling function. You have defined function `countNum(int, int)` which means it will receive two ints as arguments from the calling function, so the caller should pass them which are missing in your case. Thats the reason of error too few arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your code here:

```
int x=countNum();
```

countNum needs to be called with two integers.  eg

```
int x=countNum(n, d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't passed parameters to the `countNum` function. Use it like `int x=countNum(n,d);`

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
int x=countNum(n,0);
```

You don't need to pass `d` in, you can just pass `0` as the seed.

Also change `countNum` to this:

```
int countNum(int n,int d){
    if(n==0)
    return d;
    else
    return coutNum(n/10,d+1); // NOTE: This is the recursive bit!
}
```

Comment: when i passed arguments and my code finally compiled without error but when i runned my code but after entering the number and pressing enter  but after pressing enter the black output screen vanishes why is that so?is my code fine?or i have to cout something else?

Comment: It's because your program writes to the console and then exits. The moment it exit it closes the console. You could add another read just before the `return` to pause the program, or put a breakpoint on the `return` statement so you can see the output before the program exits.

Comment: what was that something systempause ? what was the actual thing..thanks

Comment: thanks im getting output fine but when i entered 123 it gives output 0 when i should be 3 is my code fine?

Comment: @mahnoorfatima - I've corrected your `countNum` code. It wasn't recursing on the second `return`. Note that the `d++` is now `d+1`. The `d++` would cause 0 to always be passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int countNum(int n,int d){
    if(n<10)
        return d;
    else
        return countNum(n/10, d+1);
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter number"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    int x=countNum(n, 1);
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its not giving error but when i run it and enter the number but after entering the number,screen vanishes?why is that so? also tell me that in countNum(n,d) you have passed n and d arguments and in calling function you have taken an argument zero.. shouldnt arguments same?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is not for an assignment, there are better ways to do this (just a couple of examples):

**Convert to string**

```
unsigned int count_digits(unsigned int n)
{
    std::string sValue = std::to_string(n);
    return sValue.length();
}
```

**Loop**

```
unsigned int count_digits(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int cnt = 1;
    if (n > 0)
    {
        for (n = n/10; n > 0; n /= 10, ++cnt);
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

**Tail End Recursion**

```
unsigned int count_digits(unsigned int n, unsigned int cnt = 1)
{
    if (n < 10)
        return cnt;
    else
        return count_digits(n / 10, cnt + 1);
}
```

Note:  With tail-end recursion optimizations turned on, your compiler will transform this into a loop for you - preventing the unnecessary flooding of the call stack.

Comment: it was our lab activity only through recursion..thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Inform yourself about the PMI (Principle of Mathematical Induction) on YouTube. It makes recursion very easy. Try this:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int count(int n){
    //Base Case
    if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    // Recursive Step
    // We don't have to worry about the smaller steps.
    // Don't go deep into the recursion!
    int smallerInput  = count(n/10);
    
    //Calculation Step
    return smallerInput + 1;
}   

int main()
{   
    int num;
    cout << "Enter the number: ";
    cin >> num;
    
    cout << "The number of digits are : " << count(num) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your function is written incorrectly. For example it is not clear why it has two parameters or where it calls recursively itself.

I would write it the following way

```
int countNum( int n )
{
   return 1 + ( ( n /= 10 ) ? countNum( n ) : 0 );
}
```

Or even it would be better to define it as

```
constexpr int countNum( int n )
{
   return 1 + ( ( n / 10 ) ? countNum( n/10 ) : 0 );
}
```

Comment: Aaaaaand [segmentation fault](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fb4f9646bce4089).

Comment: I don't doubt that you would write it in that way so, strictly speaking, your answer is not wrong. Unfortunately, it is an incorrect way.

Comment: @Jefffre I made a typo. I uodated my post.

Comment: BTW there is some problem with your keyboard. It keeps changing and dropping random characters in your posts.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int countNum(int n,int d){
    if(n==0)
        return d;
    else
        return countNum(n/10,d++);
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter number"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    int x=countNum(n, 0);
    cout<<x;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Comment: when i enter number 123 i get output 0 why is that ?it should be 3 :/

Comment: @mahnoor fatima I am sorry I have not undertood your quetion. The code I showed i fine.

Comment: [**Let us continue this discussion in chat.**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungeno)

Comment: im writing a code about counting digits in integer through recursion..above is my code but when i run my code and enter 123 it gives output 0 when it should give 3 as there are three digits why is that so?

Comment: @mahnoorfatima: No, it does not even compile. Please take more care over your posts.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, your answer is fine now, as far as I can tell. (I didn't downvote you even before).

Comment: @mahnoor fatima Use countNum(n/10,++d); instead of countNum(n/10,d++);

Comment: @ Lightness it does compiles in dev c++

Comment: @mahnoorfatima: That does not mean anything useful.

Comment: thats useful and it also compiles k